# How to uncomment an xml node from the command line?

Tags: xml, regex, command-line, sed, awk

The regex to select the desired node would be something like:

```
<!--\s*<env-entry>(.*\s*)*</env-entry>\s*-->
```

where the xml file contains:

```
<!--
    <env-entry>
       <env-entry-name>solr/home</env-entry-name>
       <env-entry-value>/put/your/solr/home/here</env-entry-value>
       <env-entry-type>java.lang.String</env-entry-type>
    </env-entry>
   -->
<!--
    <other-entry>
    </other-entry>
   -->
```

How do I uncomment the selected node (probably with sed/awk)?

Comment: 1. sed requires management of joining multiple lines before  you can regex match per your example, an exercise only for the brave hearted with time to spare. awk can probably do it. 2. I notice in some of your other posts using xmlstarlet. Can't that do it? 3. Are you sure you're asking the right question? It feels like you really want a way to build specfic cfg files from a master cfg file. I think there are numerous tools that can be used for that approach (but I don't have experience with them). Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a crude solution, it might have bugs at corner cases, so test it out carefully:

```
/<!--/ {
    comment = $0
    getline
    if ($0 !~ /<env-entry>/) print comment
}

/-->/ {
    if (last_line ~ /<\/env-entry>/) next
}

{
    last_line = $0
    print
}
```

UPDATE: I forgot to mention the solution is in AWK, just in case.